# What Windows Message is causing a partial region redraw

Tags: winapi, gdi

I have some old VB6 code which draws squiggles onto a simple windows textbox using win32api and double-buffering to highlight errors/mispelled words etc.

Here it is before ...

[image]

and if I select a single letter using the mouse down, mouse move left and mouse up I get a small region redrawn - it looks like about 2 lines. Here it is after ...

[image]

I'm struggling to work out what is causing the redraw and how to subclass stuff to stop that happening - if I indeed even can.

If I look at spy++, it looks like it may be something to do with the IME, but I'm not sufficiently well versed to know for sure. I have tried stopping the default editor window from displaying following my limited understanding of what [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/wm-ime-setcontext) was suggesting.

```
Private Function ProcessBeforeMsg(ByVal p_nMsg As Long, wp As Long, lp As Long, Result As Long) As Boolean
...
    Case WM_IME_SETCONTEXT
        lp = lp And Not ISC_SHOWUICOMPOSITIONWINDOW
...
```

to no avail.

So I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

EDIT-1 - I probably should add that I am not seeing a WM_ERASEBKGND in this scenario

EDIT-2 - Here's the spy++ trace for the messages which I had thought were relevant. Messages 14-19 were the ones being recorded when this behaviour happens.
[image]

EDIT-3 So now I'm wondering if my problem is the way I am drawing the squiggles because when the cursor selects the text, the squiggles are removed on that line only. I

1. blit the contents of the textbox device context into a memoryDC
2. draw the squiggle with a polyline on that memoryDC
3. blit the contents of the memoryDC back into textboxDC

Here's the code for full disclosure

```
Private Sub PaintSquiggles(ByVal p_cMistakes As CMistakes)

    Dim l_tRect         As RECT
    Dim l_hFont         As Long
    Dim l_hFontOld      As Long
    Dim l_nWidth        As Long
    Dim l_nHeight       As Long
    Dim l_hVisibleDC    As Long
    Dim l_hHiddenDC     As Long
    Dim l_hHiddenBMP    As Long

    SendMessage m_hWnd, EM_GETRECT, ByVal CLng(0), l_tRect

    l_nWidth = l_tRect.Right - l_tRect.left
    l_nHeight = l_tRect.Bottom - l_tRect.top + 2

    l_hVisibleDC = GetDC(m_hWnd) '
    l_hHiddenDC = CreateCompatibleDC(l_hVisibleDC)
    l_hHiddenBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(l_hHiddenDC, l_nWidth, l_nHeight)
    SelectObject l_hHiddenDC, l_hHiddenBMP

    BitBlt l_hHiddenDC, 0, 0, l_nWidth, l_nHeight, l_hVisibleDC, 0, 0, vbSrcCopy

    l_hFont = SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_GETFONT, 0, ByVal 0&)
    l_hFontOld = SelectObject(l_hHiddenDC, l_hFont)

    m_nLineOffset = CalculateWordExtents(m_hWnd, l_hHiddenDC, p_cMistakes, l_tRect)
    DrawSquiggles l_hHiddenDC, p_cMistakes, m_nInverseBackColour

    BitBlt l_hVisibleDC, 0, 0, l_nWidth, l_nHeight, l_hHiddenDC, 0, 0, vbSrcCopy

    SelectObject l_hHiddenDC, l_hFontOld
    DeleteObject l_hHiddenBMP

    ReleaseDC m_hWnd, l_hHiddenDC
    DeleteObject l_hHiddenDC

    ReleaseDC m_hWnd, l_hVisibleDC
    DeleteObject l_hVisibleDC

End Sub
```

Subsequently, when the text is then selected with the mouse, it picks up the text ok but the squiggle disappears and it makes me wonder if I haven't drawn the squiggles onto the same plane (or something like that) as the text. Here's another couple of screen shots to show this. I've shifted the squiggles so that they go through the middle of the text simply for demonstration.

After drawing squiggles

[image]

After mouse-selecting text, the text remains but the squiggles disappear as if the selection area isn't picking up the plane on which the squiggles are drawn within the DC - but I'm guessing??

[image]

So are there planes within the device context which I need to merge in some way prior to blitting back to the textboxDC? Or is there something else going on.

Many thx again

Comment: No immediate messages are involved. It's a call to [InvalidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) or [InvalidateRgn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidatergn) that marks a portion of a window dirty, eligible for a repaint the next time circumstances allow for a `WM_PAINT` message to get generated.

Comment: `Textbox` is a weird beast when it comes to subclassing. It does draw many things without sending `WM_PAINT` messages. `Richtextbox` is way more controllable.

Comment: @IInspectable .. thx ...what would be generating those calls? Just wondering if I can trap anything before the region redraws

Comment: I think it is part of selection drawing. It don't have to go through `WM_PAINT`, instead it can call `GetDC` and draw whenever it wants. You have also weird discrepancy - redrawn text is placed one pixel to the left and one pixel up relative to the old text.